# How to add one more mysql database on docker container locally

Tags: java, mysql, macos, docker

I have tried to add one more mysql database on docker locally. However I receive this error: Caused by: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied`; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
when I try to execute this line of code:

```
statement.execute("CREATE DATABASE database_name");
```

Do someone know a simple way to do this ?

Comment: The database is not yet properly set up. Read the docker image documentation for details

Comment: I have been using this database for 3 month, I need to add one more database. How it could be not properly set up if I use it ?

Comment: Did you check the user privileges ?

Comment: You need to use credentials for a MySQL user that is allowed to create new databases.

Comment: Thanks @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen . It helped. Before I tried to use credentials from first database and it failed. When I tried to use credentials for MySQL it succeeded.

Comment: Do you understand what happened and why?

Answer (score 0):

error is privileges;
try create a user and grant some privileges;

Comment: I cannot create user . When I try to run this query 
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
I receive this error:
[42000][1227] Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: check contianer ,docker run,docker status .or try  [root@demo ~]# docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -d mysql:5.7.34